How set Cookie and Session Timeout Based on Logged In User in ASP.NET Core 8
I'm setting the cookie and session timeout as follows (I need to use this API. I can't use the new Identity api):
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
     options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
     ...
});

This sets the same timeout for every user. And these values are set before the user is redirected to the IDP.
How can I update the cookie and session timeout to different values once the user has logged in (but before the cookie is returned to the UI). I'm authenticating against Azure B2C and would like to use the user's role to determine the timeout.
I'm hoping there is an event I can listen for that is passed information returned from Azure that would allow me to update the timeouts once the user has successfully logged in.

I solved this by setting the openidconnect property UseTokenLifetime to true and removing the maxage cookie setting. The token timeout is set in the B2C policy. I removed the max age openidconnect setting as well from the init settings. Instead, I set it in options.Events.OnTokenValidated, however this may be redundant.
